# Python I want to replace each value of the age column

Tags: python

**I want to change the values inside the age column where if age <= 30 will be replaced as young, while age > 30 will be replaced as adult. how do i do this?**

My data set:

```
    age     cartype
    32       Truck
    68      Family
    22      Family
    42      Sports
    27      Family
    20      Sports
    30      Family
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. You are expected to make at least some attempt to solve the problem. Also, if this is for example a Pandas dataframe, then you should a) explicitly say so and b) add the `pandas` tag to your question.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question. See how to create a [mcve], and also what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['age'] = df['age'].apply(lambda age: 'young' if age <= 30 else 'adult')
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with:

```
import numpy as np
```

1. `pandas.DataFrame.le` *(less than or equal)*

```
df['age'] = np.where(df['age'].le(30),'young','adult')
```

2. [`pandas.DataFrame.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) *(greater than)*

```
df['age'] = np.where(df['age'].gt(30),'adult','young')
```

Both print:

```
Out[801]: 

     age cartype
0  adult   Truck
1  adult  Family
2  young  Family
3  adult  Sports
4  young  Family
5  young  Sports
6  young  Family
```